# Как настроить FTP на IIS через роутер?

Tags: ftp, iis, роутер

У меня есть белый ip-адрес и я пытаюсь настроить ftp-сервер на iis'е. При открытии по внутреннему ip-адресу всё отлично работает, а вот по внешнему получаю ошибку (firewall полностью отключил - не помогает):

> Ошибка папки FTP
>
> ---
>
> В ходе открытия папки на FTP-сервере произошла ошибка. Убедитесь, что у вас есть разрешение открывать эту папку.
>
> Подробности:
> 200 Type set to A.
>
> 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,202,246,61).
>
> ---
>
> ОК

При некоторых настройках сообщение меняется на

> Ошибка папки FTP
>
> ---
>
> В ходе открытия папки на FTP-сервере произошла ошибка. Убедитесь, что у вас есть разрешение открывать эту папку.
>
> Подробности:
> Не удается установить связь с сервером
>
> ---
>
> ОК

Как сделать, чтобы с внешнего адреса тоже открывалось?

Answer (score 1):

## Предварительная подготовка

- Надо иметь белый ip-адрес от провайдера
- На роутере должен быть настроена выдача фиксированного ip (в локальной сети) компьютеру - у меня это будет 192.168.1.202

  [image: настройка фиксированного ip на роутере]
- Временно отключаем firewall - так проще проверять, а когда всё будет готово - включим обратно и настроим

## Действуем по любой инструкции

1. Устанавливаем IIS
2. Создаём FTP-сайт и указываем желаемый порт (по умолчанию 21, я для примера использую 4444), отключаем SSL
3. Указываем доступ для зарегистрированных пользователей
4. Создаём локального пользователя windows с нужными логином и паролем
5. Проверяем через ftp://localhost:4444 или локальный ip ftp://192.168.1.202:4444 - должно уметь запрашивать логин и пароль свежесозданного пользователя.

## Разбираемся с настройками портов в IIS'е:

6. В IIS для компьютера идём в Поддержку брандмауэра FTP:

   [image: Поддержка брандмауэра FTP]
7. Указываем там диапазон портов, который будет использоваться для пассивных соединений

   [image: Указываем диапазон портов]
8. В IIS для сайта (может можно и для компьютера - мне было лень проверять) идём в Поддержку брандмауэра FTP:

   [image: Поддержка брандмауэра FTP для сайта]
9. Указываем внешний ip-адрес - не тот, который в локальной сети, а тот, который выдал провайдер интернета (для примера использую 5.111.222.33):

   [image: Указываем ip-адрес]
10. На этом этапе должно полностью без ошибок работать ftp://localhost:4444 и ftp://192.168.1.202:4444. Т. е. при открытии должны запрашиваться логин и пароль, а после их ввода должна открыться папка. Если изоляция пользователей в свойствах ftp-сайта отключена, то можно в папку заранее положить какой-то файл и он должен отобразиться.

## Настраиваем проброс портов на роутере

11. Выставляем проброс основного порта ftp на роутере

    [image: Проброс ftp-порта на роутере]
12. На этом этапе при открытии ftp://5.111.222.33:4444 будет появляться окно ввода логина и пароля, но если их ввести, вместо открытия папки будет происходить одна из указанных в вопросе ошибок.
13. Добавляем проброс диапазона портов, указанного на шаге 7.

    [image: Проброс пассивных портов]
14. На этом этапе по адресу ftp://5.111.222.33:4444 всё должно работать. Впрочем, может понадобиться перезагрузить компьютер.

## Включаем firewall

15. Включаем обратно firewall и идём в разрешения для порграмм

    [image: Разрешение для программ]
16. Находим в списке FTP Сервер и ставим галочку

    [image: Разрешение доступа для FTP]

## Готово

17. Всё должно по-прежнему работать
18. При необходимости можно настроить ssl